# Хранение статической переменной в сборке

Tags: c#, .net, assembly

Правильно ли я думаю, что код одной сборки dll может быть использован разными программами?

Если это так, то если в этой сборке будет статическая переменная и одна программа изменит значение, то другая программа будет использовать эту измененную переменную?

P.S. я, конечно, проверил: нет, не изменит, просто хочу чтоб мне пояснили где именно я ошибаюсь

Comment: Каждая программа имеет свое отдельное адресное пространство в памяти операционной системы, поэтому даже при использовании одной и той же библиотеки и статической переменной все равно каждая программа имеет "свой собственный" экземпляр статической переменной.

Comment: @Bulson, тогда следующий вопрос: в какой момент создается (выделяется память под него) эта статическая переменная: когда запускается программа, когда подгружается сборка или когда вызывается статический конструктор?

Comment: В принципе можно считать, что в момент обращения к классу в котором содержится эта ваша статическая переменная, происходит вызов статического конструктора и в этот момент в куче происходит выделение под нее память.

Comment: Между прочим существуют так называемые pipes(каналы) для взаимодействия между собой программ в пределах одной ОС. Ройте лучше в этом направлении.

Comment: Вот вам [ссылочка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx) для затравки

Comment: @Bulson, что-то я не вижу связи между каналами и статическими переменными(

Comment: Я, исходя из вашего вопроса, смело позволил себе предположить, что вы хотите передавать данные между вашими программами, вот и решил вам таким образом помочь.

Comment: @Bulson, нет, мне просто интересно:) А в каком адресном пространстве находятся сами сборки, если это не адресное пространство процесса?

Comment: Когда ОС запускает программу(процесс) она передает ей (текущее окружение: значение переменных среды типа `Path`, `TMP`, `Temp` и проч.), а также выделяет память под стек (если я не ошибаюсь, для 32 разрядных это будет 1 мегабайт), а еще выделяет процессу Thread для его работы(исполнения). Запущенный процесс как бы видит, что кроме него и ОС больше никого не существует, а для ссылочных типов через команду `new` он запрашивает у системы дополнительную память из т.н. кучи. Как-то так. Я думаю меня еще поправят здешние ребята по деталям, но в общем это так.

Comment: и снова же не понятно: _Запущенный процесс как бы видит, что кроме него и ОС больше никого не существует_, но при этом сборка находится не в адресной памяти процесса.

Comment: "сборка находится не в адресной..." вы имеете в виду `dll`-ку? Ну, так из нее же по мере работы процесса "подтягиваются" нужные классы, но только в момент необходимости, т.е. когда надо процесс "считывает" нужный класс из библиотеки, а до тех пор этот класс лежит внутри файла сборки и "в ус не дует".

Comment: @Bulson, чуть проясняется, но ведь _Запущенный процесс как бы видит, что кроме него и ОС больше никого не существует_. Откуда процесс берет сборку (dll)?

Comment: Когда программа компилируется, то компилятор определяет(считывает конфиг файл проекта) от каких библиотек программа зависит и где они находятся: глобальный кэш GAC или же это локальная библиотека, которая должна быть в одном с программой каталоге.

Comment: Сборки находятся в адресном пространстве процесса, конечно. Но код всё равно компилируется на лету JIT-компиляторов в каждом из процессов. В любом случае, статическая переменная существует в памяти процесса (наверное, в куче), и не разделяется между процессами.

Comment: @VladD, в этой теме у меня большой пробел, поэтому возникают такие вопросы
1) _Сборки находятся в адресном пространстве процесса, конечно_ - так все же используется одна сборка несколькими процессами одновременно? Если да, то получается, что адресные пространства процессов пересекаются, разве нет?
2) _Но код всё равно компилируется на лету JIT-компиляторов в каждом из процессов_ - а если это не управляемый код, а уже dll на чистом С?

Comment: @Qutrix: Ну да, но общим для нескольких процессов является неизменяемая часть кода (если она есть). Скорее всего реальный машинный код из IL производится JIT'тером, и значит, он не неизменяемый (он же генерируется на лету) и для каждого процесса свой. А уж данные-то точно не разделяются между процессами.

Comment: @Qutrix: Ну, для read-only-кусков одна и та же физическая память может реально соответствовать каким-то кускам в адресном пространстве разных процессов. Но для изменяемой памяти, то есть переменных, нет, иначе можно было бы их одного процесса менять кусок данных другого, а это неправильно.

Comment: @Qutrix: А вот если это нативная DLL, то её **код** через механизм memory-mapped-file отображается в read-only-память обоих процессов. Только код, не данные. Данные у каждого процесса в любом случае свои. Соответственно кусок с данными копируется для каждого  процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общее принцип работы процессов заключается в том, что между ними может разделяться *код*, но не *данные*.*

Статические переменные (а в C# это могут быть лишь статические поля класса) в C# создаются в момент загрузки содержащего их класса. Это не только оптимизация использования памяти (не используемые в программе классы не занимают лишнюю память и время инициализации), а и необходимость. Дело в том, что в сборке может быть потенциально бесконечное количество классов.

Пример: если у нас есть обобщённый класс

```
class C<T> where T: new()
{
    static T t = new T();
}
```

то у нас возможны классы `C<object>`, `C<C<object>>`, `C<C<C<object>>>` и т. д., так что разместить статические поля в бинарном файле программы просто невозможно.

Для других языков, в которых количество типов потенциально ограничено и определено во время компиляции, и статические POD-типы могут быть помещены в бинарник. Тем не менее, при загрузке процесс получает *копию* этих данных (например, посредством использования [COW](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8)-сегмента памяти).

---

*Для Microsoft .NET даже это неверно, т. к. *большая* часть кода производится JIT-компилятором, и размещается в динамической памяти, т. е. для каждого процесса код может отличаться.